# Fatal Exception When Not Connected to Internet

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to learn `Kotlin` and `rxjava`. I have a very simple app with just a `button` that you click that fetches some data from a website.

Everything works fine unless I turn off of my cellular data, in which case I get a fatal exception with no explanation of why.

> My code:

```
// In the activity's onCreate
ViewObservable.clicks(button)
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe{
            fetchTest().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe{ s:String -> 
                        textView.text = s
                    }      
        }

// Elsewhere in the activity code
@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun fetchTest(): Observable<String> {
    val url = URL(MY_URL)
    val httpConnection = url.openConnection()

    var stream = httpConnection.inputStream

    val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(stream))

    val response = reader.readLines().reduce { x, y -> x + y }
    stream?.close()

    return Observable.just(response)
}
```

> When I'm in debug mode, the error occurs here:

```
var stream = httpConnection.inputStream
```

And the logcat is entirely unhelpful:

```
02-12 10:13:37.748    8616-8645/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
Process: com.example.app, PID: 8616
```

I know the error is because there's no network connection, but adding a try/catch can't catch it so I don't know what to do

Comment: What's a stacktrace after these lines?

Comment: @Michael That's all logcat says after it crashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view observable's subscriber needed to implement onError as well

Comment: You can edit your own question to indicate that it was resolved and is not really open.